# Angular $watch within loop closure not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, closures, watch

I am trying to dynamically add watchers within a loop. First I am watching for when the length of an array of `display_groups` changes, and when it does I want to make sure each display group has a watch on the `current_page` property (this is for pagination).

I have added a closure within my loop for `watchDelegate` which returns the current page property of the associated display group. This is actually all working well, by my problem is that I need to access another property of the same `display_group` to execute the pagination logic, and I cannot find a way to access the correct display group. I added another function `displayGroupDelegate` below, but it always returns the display group of the last loop.

I am reasonably new to angular (and JS closures), so any advice appreciated. Thanks.

```
    display_group_watchers = []
    #watch for when display groups are added/removed
    $scope.$watch 'display_groups.length', ((newValue, oldValue) ->
      if newValue and (newValue != oldValue)
        for watcher in display_group_watchers
          watcher() #this clears out existing watchers
        display_group_watchers = [] #reset the array

        #set up a watch for the current page of each display group
        for key, display_group of $scope.display_groups
          watchDelegate = ((j) ->
            ->
              $scope.display_groups[j].current_page
          )(key)

          displayGroupDelegate = ((j) ->
            ->
              $scope.display_groups[j]
          )(key)

          watcher = $scope.$watch watchDelegate, ((newValue, oldValue) ->
            #only fire the change if navigating to a page i.e. going from undefined to 1 is just the inital load of data
            if newValue and (newValue != oldValue) and not (newValue ==1 and oldValue == undefined)
              ########this always returns the last display_group, not the one from the current loop!!!!
              console.log "user_tasks_to_expand_sym: #{displayGroupDelegate().user_tasks_to_expand_sym}"
          ), true
          display_group_watchers.push(watcher)
    ), true
```